# Is there a way to trim a String without allocating another one?

Tags: string, rust, trim

I have a file in the CSV format with a first column of data that represents item code optionally ended with `"UNIUNI"` or mixed case of these chars, loaded by means of a barcode reader. I need to trim away the last `"UNI"`s.

I wrote this function:

```
fn main() {
    // Ok: from "9846UNIUNI" to "9846"
    println!("{}", read_csv_rilev("9846UNIUNI".to_string()));
    
    // Wrong: from "9846uniuni" to "9846"
    println!("{}", read_csv_rilev("9846uniuni".to_string()));
}

fn read_csv_rilev(code: String) -> String {
    code
        //.to_uppercase() /*Unstable feature in Rust 1.1*/
        .trim_right_matches("UNI")
        .to_string()
}
```

The ideal function signature looks like:

```
fn read_csv_rilev(mut s: &String)
```

but probably an in-place action on a `String` is not a good idea. In fact, in the Rust standard library there isn't anything to do this excluding `String::pop()`.

Comment: `.trim_right_matches()` is going to be stable in Rust 1.2

Comment: And `.trim_right()`, which you can use to do this without `.to_string()`. Just use the length of the trimmed str to truncate with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there a way to trim a `String` without allocating another one?

Yes, you can use [`truncate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate) to remove trailing parts of the string:

```rust
const TRAILER: &'static str = "UNI";

fn read_csv_rilev(s: &mut String) {
    while s.ends_with(TRAILER) {
        let len = s.len();
        let new_len = len.saturating_sub(TRAILER.len());
        s.truncate(new_len);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut code = "Hello WorldUNIUNIUNI".into();
    
    read_csv_rilev(&mut code);
    
    assert_eq!("Hello World", code);
}
```

You don't *need* to mess with the allocated string at all. You can use the same logic and make successive subslices of the string. This is basically how `trim_right_matches` works, but a bit less generic:

```rust
const TRAILER: &'static str = "UNI";

fn read_csv_rilev(mut s: &str) -> &str {
    while s.ends_with(TRAILER) {
        let len = s.len();
        let new_len = len.saturating_sub(TRAILER.len());
        s = &s[..new_len];
    }
    s
}

fn main() {
    let code = "Hello WorldUNIUNIUNI";

    let truncated = read_csv_rilev(code);

    assert_eq!("Hello World", truncated);
}
```

In general, I'd probably go with the second solution.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but there is a nice two liner, trim_right_matches is deprecated now, but trim_end_matches() returns a &str with the length you want

```rust
fn read_csv_rilev(code: &mut String) {
        // code.to_uppercase();
        let l = code.trim_end_matches("UNI").len();
        code.truncate(l);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> but probably an in-place action on a String is not a good idea.

The *binding* is mutable in `mut s: &String`, not the string itself. You would take `s: &mut String` if you wanted to mutate the string itself.

That said, I don't think there's anything in the standard library to do this.

Comment: Thank you Steve. You are in right. Sometimes the hands on keyboard are not connected so well... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the [`owning_ref`](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs) crate, which lets you return both a `&str` and its backing `String` at the same time:

```
extern crate owning_ref;
use owning_ref::StringRef;

fn read_csv_rilev(code: String) -> StringRef {
    StringRef::new(code).map(|s| s.trim_right_matches("UNI"))
}
```