# No method named `push_str` found for type `&str` after trimming a string

Tags: scope, rust

I keep getting this error. I'm assuming it's because I shadow `answer` trimming it since when I comment that part out I don't get the error anymore. I don't understand why that is.

```
fn main() {
    let mut answer = String::new();
    let num = 40;

    if num % 2 == 0 {
        answer.push_str("fact2 ");
    }
    if num % 5 == 0 {
        answer.push_str("fact5 ");
    }

    let answer = answer.trim();
    answer.push_str("bob was here");
    println!("{}", answer);
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `push_str` found for type `&str` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:12
   |
13 |     answer.push_str("bob was here");
   |            ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assuming it's because I shadow `answer` trimming it

Yes. [`String::trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim) returns a `&str`:

```
pub fn trim(&self) -> &str
```

`&str` does not have the `push_str` method.

See also:

- [Why does `name = *name.trim();` give me `expected struct `std::string::String`, found str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41198951/155423)
- [Efficient trimming of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31276059/155423)
- [How to "crop" characters off the beginning of a string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38447780/155423)

Answer (score 2):

You're right, `let answer = answer.trim();` is the problem. It sets `answer` to have type `&str`, and that `push_str` is defined for a mutable `String`.

You can fix it by changing that line to:

```
answer = answer.trim().to_string();
```